# RGBA to hex color converter with color merging

Tags: web-development, color

I'm trying to compare the colors of different websites.

One website states its colors with RGBA and has for example `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55)` on a white background. I would like to convert the result into a hex color code.

Is there a straightforward converter for this task?

I would expect a Web app, but otherwise for Windows 10.

Comment: For everyone trying to answer this question: a tool that allows entering 1 value only does not meet the requirements. Any tool needs to accept input for 2 values: an RGBA value and a background color. It then needs to put the alphaic value over the background and output the result.

Comment: Just for convertion this can be helpful: https://cssgenerator.org/rgba-and-hex-color-generator.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a fully-fledged solution for your case, but [Linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx) can help. It's gratis and works on Windows 10.

The following script will convert merge an alpha color with a background color and output the resulting hex code:

```
// Define input here
var bgcolor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
var alphacolor =  System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((int)(0.55*255), 0, 0, 0);

// Calculation
float factor = alphacolor.A / 255f;
int red = (int) (bgcolor.R * (1 - factor) + alphacolor.R * factor);
int green = (int) (bgcolor.G * (1 - factor) + alphacolor.G * factor);
int blue = (int) (bgcolor.B * (1 - factor) + alphacolor.B * factor);
var result = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);

// Output as hex
Console.WriteLine($"#{result.A:X2}{result.R:X2}{result.G:X2}{result.B:X2}");
```

For the given input `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55)` and `white` background, the result is

```
#FF727272
```

Hints: you need to convert decimal values like 0.55 using the formula `(int)(<yourvalue>*255)`. This can only be omitted for the value 0, because the result is 0 as well in this specific case.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this web](https://www.hexcolortool.com) for your color conversion.
But while in rgba you have a value for transparency, in hex the isn't.

Comment: That's a nice tool but it doesn't really solve my problem of wanting to compare colors in this case. Is there a way where I can specify the background so that I get the resulting color when transparency gets factored in?

Comment: @Christian Add those requirements to your Question.

Answer (score -1):

This [tool](https://contrast-ratio.com) should allow you to do this quite well for two colors.

It accepts html color names (e.g. black, white, dark red etc.), hex code (#fff, #000 etc.) and rgba colors (rgba(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.2) etc.)

[image]